# When Create ensureIndex in mongoDb

Tags: mongodb

I'm new in mongoDb, And I don't understand when (and why) use `ensureIndex`

for example i have this collection

```
db.films.insert( { "Type" : "DVD", "Title" : "Matrix, The", "Released" :1999} )
db.films.insert( { "Type" : "DVD", "Title" : "Blade Runner", "Released" :1982 } )
db.films.insert( { "Type" : "DVD", "Title" : "Toy Story 3", "Released" :2010} )
```

if I try with

```
db.films.find(). min ( { Released: 1995 } ) . max ( { Released : 2005 } )
```

i have this error

```
error: {
    "$err" : "no index found for specified keyPattern: {} min: { Released: 1995.0 } max: { Released: 2005.0 }",
    "code" : 10367
}
```

I have to do

```
db.films.ensureIndex( { "Released": 1 } )
```

and all Works.

why this does not work?

```
db.films.find(). min ( { "Released": 1995 } ) . max ( { "Released" : 2005 } )
```

and when i have to use

```
. hint ( { Released : 1 } )
```

I try to do

```
db.films.ensureIndex( { "Released": 1 } )
db.films.ensureIndex( { "Released": -1 } )
```

and

```
db.films.find() . min ( { Released: 1995 } ) . max ( { Released : 2005 } ). hint ( { Released : -1 } )
```

this is my error

```
error: {
    "$err" : "requested keyPattern does not match specified keys",
    "code" : 10365
}
```

Comment: Your query is incorrect for min and max; ensure index makes sure the collection has index.

db.films.find({Released: {$gte: 1995, $lt: 2005}});

Comment: The $max and $min operators require indexes to work. Instead, use $gte and $lte if you don't want to create any indexes.

Comment: @Sumeet db.films.find(). min ( { "Released": 1995 } ) . max ( { "Released" : 2005 } ) without create index...

Comment: You have the wrong approach here and should have listened to @java_dude right at the beginning. `min()` and `.max()` are for clipping indexes. What you **want** are [**`$gte`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/gte/#op._S_gte) and [**`$lte`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/lte/) within your find. Read the links and learn them. With an index they are very efficient. Getting used to `.min()` and `.max()` will get you into trouble. Unlearn, and re-learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is not working because min() requires an index on a field and forces the query to use the index.

Comment: and what do you say about it  `. hint ( { Released : -1 } ) `

Comment: db.films.find(). min ( { "Released": 1995 } ) . max ( { "Released" : 2005 } ).hint( { Released : 1 } ) is it not workiong for you ?

Comment: hint force the query to use a specific index and i think what you have done is correct . Which version of mongodb you are using.

Answer (score 1):

`min()` and `max()` are index operators. Instead of constrainng a set of results from an index by a range (`$lt`, `$lte`, `$gt` and `$gte`) they actually decide how much of the index is scanned by selecting a lower and upper limit of data points. You can see this most noticeably if you also do an `explain()`.

Without an index MongoDB cannot restrict the index.

It should be noted that if you wish to go the route of using `min` and `max` then for descending indexes you will need to reverse the values within the two functions to match the reversed index.

In all honesty it is better to leave the range of index scanning to MongoDB most of the tme.

If your query:

```
db.films.find() . min ( { Released: 1995 } ) . max ( { Released : 2005 } ). hint ( { Released : -1 } )
```

Doesn't work it means that MongoDB cannot find the range you specify in your index.